# Best way to reserve memory for a array of n length in .bss

Tags: windows, assembly, fasm

So I have this program which inserts in an uninitialized byte array, an n-length array of bytes.

However my question is if there is a better way of storing data in the .bss section without having to specify a fixed number, here `100h` for the inputted bytes since this reduces portability.

PS: I don't want to use any windows API functions such as `VirtualAlloc` or `malloc`

```
section ".bss" readable writeable
    BYTE_ARRAY db 100h dup(?)

.code
start:
   call get_input
   mov edx, eax
   xor ecx, ecx

input_loop:
    call get_input
    
    mov byte [BYTE_ARRAY+ecx], al

    inc ecx
    cmp ecx, eax
    jnz input_loop

;ExitProcess and .idata...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"I don't want to use any windows API functions"_. Why? Sounds to me like you want to do runtime memory allocation, so do runtime memory allocation. The size of the .bss section is stored in the executable header, which is written at link time.

Comment: `.bss` is inherently compile time. The size has to be in the file in a header. If you want dynamic allocation you will need to call OS function. Alternatively, check whether your program can work with reusing a fixed size buffer.